# gem install rails does not work

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

I am working on ubuntu and rvm. In any case I tried to use sudo gem (any command) it does not recognize gem as command. In addition if I use gem seperately as:

```
gem install rails
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: rails
```

I got that error. I cannot see the reason.

rvm version 1.10.3
ruby version 1.8.7
gem version 1.6.7

What is the possible reason behind this?

Comment: It finds `gem` command. It cannot install rails. Check your network.

Comment: Do you have working Internet? Do you have a firewall that only lets through things like HTTP and FTP? Do you have some sort of security software that would not give `gem` the permission to connect to the network?

Comment: I solve that problem bu now it gives  "Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0) in any repository" error only. I search for any firewall but no one expect on my router.

Comment: I guess I have a problem about network, but now I cannot find the reason just like a computer noob

Comment: I found the problem. This is because a program that is behaving like a proxy, also the silly fact is Ubuntu does not show the proxy settings correctly :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Re-install all rvm and ruby and the gems, solved my problem.